# Strange ui-view behavior when managing states with Angular ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've built a basic plunker where I'm trying to manage a list of posts with two separate post filters in the header. When a filter is clicked, an "active" class is appended to the link. Since two categories of filters can be applied (tag and order_by), a filter link inherits the other filter's paramater through `$stateParams`, if the paramater exists.

Now to the issue.. when a filter link is clicked, it seems to render a duplicate ui-view and I can't figure out why.

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/FA0lQV?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Your index file has your header included, then you are calling in your index files again where your `ui-view` is on the page via your `home` state.

The simplest solution is to replace the `templateUrl` in your `home` state with `template: "<ui-view></ui-view>"`

This will get rid of the duplicate header calls and allow for the `ui-view` directive to be there for the children views.

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/52ysX9fmNbl93f9Ln5Ju?p=preview